# Unicast Vs Portable Remote Object

Tags: java, rmi, iiop

What is the basic difference between `java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject` and `java.rmi.PortableRemoteObject`.

I know that one is used for JRMP and the other for IIOP,but can anyone explain it in a lay man's language.I'm new to Java.Also can we use a Protable Remote Object for JRMP? If not,why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi-iiop/rmi_iiop_pg.html

> When do I use UnicastRemoteObject vs
>   PortableRemoteObject?
>
> UnicastRemoteObject should be used as
>   the superclass for the object
>   implementation in RMI programming.
>   PortableRemoteObject should be used in
>   RMI-IIOP programming. If
>   PortableRemoteObject is used, you can
>   switch the transport protocol to
>   either JRMP or IIOP during runtime.

Comment: If you use either of these base classes you will get the associated protocol. If *neither* of these base classes is used, you can use *both* protocols at runtime simultaneously, via UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject() and PortableRemoteObject.exportObject().

Comment: I literally quoted the JavaSE documentation.  If it's incorrect, please open a bug with Oracle.